# Extracting a part of String using grep/sed/awk

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a text file with something like this:

```
duration:       17100
series:         2016
episode:        58
modesizes:      original: hd1=9120MB,hd2=7543MB,sd1=4872MB,high1=2833MB,low1=634MB
runtime:        285


duration:       13740
series:         2016
episode:        59
modesizes:      original: hd1=9024MB,hd2=7203MB,sd1=5104MB,high1=2950MB,low1=570MB
runtime:        229
```

I would like to extract `duration`, `episode` and `modesizes`. 
Output should look like this:

```
13740,59,9024MB,7203MB,5104MB,2950MB,570MB
```

Comment: why doesn't first set of numbers feature in your output? and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/duration|episode/{printf "%s,", $2} /modesizes/{gsub(/[^=,]+=/,"",$3); print $3}' file
```

---

Explanation:

- `/duration|episode/` if the line matches `duration` or `episode`

  - `printf "%s,", $2` then print the field with the value
- `/modesizes/` if the line matches `modesizes`

  - `gsub(/[^=,]+=/,"",$3)` then remove the identifiers and the equal sign
  - `print $3` and print the changed field

---

With your input example it prints:

```
17100,58,9120MB,7543MB,4872MB,2833MB,634MB
13740,59,9024MB,7203MB,5104MB,2950MB,570MB
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `grep` with `pcre` regex

```
$ grep -oP '(duration|episode):\s*\K\d+|\d+MB' ip.txt | pr -ats, -7
17100,58,9120MB,7543MB,4872MB,2833MB,634MB
13740,59,9024MB,7203MB,5104MB,2950MB,570MB
```

- `(duration|episode):\s*\K` positive lookbehind to check `duration` or `episode` followed by `:`, zero or more spaces. This is not part of output
- `\d+` one or more digits
- `|\d+MB` alternate pattern, one or more digits ending with `MB`

Output so obtained is then styled using `pr` with `,` as separator and max of `7` columns

Answer (score 0):

A sed solution:

```
sed -E -e \
    '/duration:/{
    N;N;N;N
    s/duration:\s*([0-9]*).*episode:\s*([0-9]*).*hd1=([0-9]*MB),hd2=([0-9]*MB),sd1=([0-9]*MB),high1=([0-9]*MB),low1=([0-9]*MB).*/\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6/
}' < input_file
```

It outputs:

```
17100,58,9120MB,7543MB,4872MB,2833MB


13740,59,9024MB,7203MB,5104MB,2950MB
```

It preserves the empty lines.

If you don't want these:

```
sed -E -n -e \
   '/duration:/{
    N;N;N;N
    s/duration:\s*([0-9]*).*episode:\s*([0-9]*).*hd1=([0-9]*MB),hd2=([0-9]*MB),sd1=([0-9]*MB),high1=([0-9]*MB),low1=([0-9]*MB).*/\1,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6/
    p
    d
}' < input_file
```